# How to implement double SELECT in recursive cte on SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I faced a problem while implementing a recursive query on SQL, including double selection from the database at each iteration.

I have two tables, describing the oriented graph, where each nodes located at grid:

```
table nodes:
id
grid_x
grid_y

table edges:
source
target
```

And want to implement selection of nodes, which located at adjacent positions on the grid to the right of the initial node with selection of parents and childs at each iteration.

Selection of right nodes realized by following recursive query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    cte(id, grid_x, grid_y) AS (
        SELECT id, grid_x, grid_y
        FROM nodes WHERE id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT current.id, current.grid_x, current.grid_y
        FROM nodes AS current, cte AS prev
    WHERE current.grid_x = prev.grid_x + 1
        AND current.grid_y = prev.grid_y
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte;
```

let the data in the database have the following representation
[image: graph]

i.e.

```
Table nodes:
 id | grid_x | grid_y |   |  
----+--------+--------+---+--
  0 |      0 |      0 |   |  
 13 |      1 |      0 |   |  
 14 |      3 |      0 |   |  
  5 |     -1 |      1 |   |  
  1 |      0 |      1 |   |  
  2 |      1 |      1 |   |  
  3 |      2 |      1 |   |  
  4 |      4 |      1 |   |  
 12 |     -2 |      2 |   |  
  6 |     -1 |      2 |   |  
  7 |      0 |      2 |   |  
  8 |      2 |      2 |   |  
  9 |      3 |      2 |   |  
 10 |      4 |      2 |   |  
 11 |      6 |      2 |   |  

Table edges:

 id | source | target 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      0 |      5
  2 |      0 |      1
  3 |      1 |      7
  4 |      5 |      6
  5 |      5 |     12
  6 |     13 |      2
  7 |     13 |      3
  8 |      2 |      8
  9 |      3 |      8
 10 |      3 |      9
 11 |     14 |      3
 12 |     14 |      4
 13 |      4 |     10
 14 |      4 |     11
```

query above will select nodes 0 and 13

I want to select at each iteration not only the nodes located on the right, but also the child and parent nodes, if they are not already in the cte.

For example, a query that should also select child nodes should start from node 0. Then at firts iteration select nodes 13, 5 and 1, at second iteration select nodes 2, 3, 12, 6, 7, at third iteration - nodes 8, 9 and at fourth iteration - node 10.

The query, which select at each iteration parents and childs, which not already in cte with neighbor right nodes at grid should select all nodes from picture at finish.

I tried to write the following query for select right nodes with their childs:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    cte(id, grid_x, grid_y) AS (
        SELECT id, grid_x, grid_y
        FROM nodes WHERE id = 0
    UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT current.id, current.grid_x, current.grid_y
        FROM nodes AS current, cte AS prev
        WHERE current.grid_x = prev.grid_x + 1
            AND current.grid_y = prev.grid_y
        UNION
        SELECT c.id, c.grid_x, c.grid_y
        FROM nodes AS c, cte AS p, edges AS e
        WHERE p.id = e.source AND c.id = e.target
            AND here should be checking on existing node at cte
        )
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte;
```

But `recursive reference to query "cte" must not appear within a subquery`

Query like this

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    cte(id, grid_x, grid_y) AS (
        SELECT id, grid_x, grid_y
        FROM nodes WHERE id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT current.id, current.grid_x, current.grid_y
        FROM nodes AS current, edges AS e, cte AS prev
    WHERE (current.grid_x = prev.grid_x + 1
        AND current.grid_y = prev.grid_y)
        OR (prev.id = e.source AND e.target = current.id)
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte;
```

But this query selects only node 0

Please, help me solve this problem.

Comment: Could you, please, provide the exact table-formated result that you want and the exact table-formated data the you have in entry?

Comment: @ToddBarry . . . To add to the above comment, a db fiddle of some sort would also be helpful.

Comment: I added table-formatted data from database. I want to get nodes by described algorithm, which select childs and right nodes at each iteration. So, if I start with node 0, I want to get nodes 0, 13, 5, 1, 2, 3, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, as I described above. I want to get their id, grid_x and grid_y columns

Comment: what about 14 and its descendant series

Comment: @DarkRob they are not selects, because 14 isn't a child of any previous selected nodes and it isn't located at adjacent position righter of any previous selected nodes. Similar for descendant nodes of 14

Comment: @DarkRob (except node 10, because it located righter of 9, which selected at previous iteration)